# mongodb, sorting by geoNear and date?

Tags: mongodb, date, sorting, proximity

how to sort by proximity and date in mongoDB?
I tried this. But they just sort by date:

```
   coll.find({'date':{$gte:date},'location':{$nearSphere:[lat,lng]}}).sort({'date':1}).execFind(function (err, docs) {})
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no direct way to use `$near` or `$nearSphere` and sort by another field, because both of these operators already sort the results of doing a `find()`. When you sort again by 'date', you're re-sorting the results. What you can do, however, is grab results from the `$nearSphere` incrementally, and sort each set of results. For example:

```
function sortByDate(a, b) { return a.date - b.date; }

// how many results to grab at a time
var itersize = 10;
// this will hold your final, two-way sorted results
var sorted_results = new Array();
for (var i=0, last=db.coll.count(); i<last-itersize; i+=itersize) {
    var results = db.coll.find( {"date":{$gte:date},
                                 // longitude, then latitude
                                 "location":[lng, lat]} ).skip(i).limit(itersize).toArray();
    // do date sorting app-side for each group of nearSphere-sorted results
    sorted_results = sorted_results.concat( results.sort(sortByDate) );
}
```

You should also be aware of the order you specify geospatial coordinates in mongodb queries. MongoDB uses the [geojson](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) spec, which does coordinates in X, Y, Z order (i.e., longitude, latitude).

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use $geoNear in an aggregate :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

You can sort on your date and distance in the aggregate :

```
    coll.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ lng, lat ] },
        key: "location",
        spherical: true,
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        query: { "date": {"$gte": date} }
     }
   },
   {$sort: {"dist.calculated":1, "date": 1}}
])
```