# Sorting by $geoNear in Aggregation framework with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

Was reading about $ geoNear in Mongo, but can not be used for the following purpose: I've the following JSON:

```
{
user: "bruno",
location: [30.45, 45.5],
other_fields...
}
```

I would like to apply geoNear similar to the following command to get to do in my application pipeline. Is it possible? I want to sort by geographic location field.

```
db.places.find({coords:{$geoWithin:{$center:[[-23.017812,-45.544617],10]}}})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to find all places within distance `10` from your center point `[-23.017812,-45.544617]`, you would format your query like so:

```
db.runCommand({ geoNear: 'places', 
                near: [-23.017812, -45.544617],
                maxDistance: 10 })
```

You can read more about the geoNear options [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/).

Comment: I understand how it works, but i cannot work with aggregation. I'm creating an application that uses GPS and pipeline operations together. GPS filter is very useful for my application.

Comment: Could you clarify how this needs to fit into aggregation, or what sort of aggregation you're trying to do? Please post the aggregation operations you're using in the pipeline.

Comment: I'm using various operations, my JSON can contain numeric data, gps, text, dates etc.. Then use gt, gte, match, etc. $ regex. Within. It's to filter data with specific conditions. Example of JSON:
json1 = 
{
 location: [10.0, 12.3],
 thing: "pizza",
 prize: 12.99
}

json2= 
{
 location: [9.0, -12.3],
 thing: "pizza",
 prize: 19.10
}

json3=
{
 location: [-5.0, 3.3],
 thing: "coffee",
 prize: 1.99
}


I create filters like: locate establishments that have thing for pizza, $ match on pizza. Then sort them by price and end me the closest place. Understand?

Comment: If all you're doing is filtering data, it doesn't sound like you need the aggregation framework. You're just using db.places.find(), right? Have you looked into [geoSearch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoSearch/)? Basically, you would pass the query like: `{ geoSearch : "places", near : [-23, -45], maxDistance : 10, search : { type : "pizza", price : { $lt: 20}}}`. You can't sort both by price and distance in the same query, but you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777130/mongodb-sorting-by-geonear-and-date) for a possible solution. Does that help?

Comment: My thesis is about collective intelligence and i'm contributing to a open source project and i necessary to create a pipeline filter using gps. In my case it's necessary to make a lot of forms of visualization of data. But unfortunately haven't conditions to use simply 'find'. I was reading abount neo in this link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/geoNear/ and it's contains: 'You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.'.
But I don't know, how to use it. Can You help me? If I to use in get in the first pipeline would be very important for my thesys. Tks.

Comment: For the use case you described above, you would just stick that geoSearch query into a `db.runCommand`. So, in the Mongo shell, you would type in: `db.runCommand({ geoSearch : "places", near : [-23, -45], maxDistance : 10, search : { type : "pizza", price : { $lt: 20}}})` to return a list of documents of type "pizza" with price < 20 within 10 units of the -23, -45 location. However, if you're set on aggregation because a later step of your workflow needs the other aggregation operators, for example, if you wanted to find the cheapest pizza place within 10 distance units (tbc)

Comment: Bruno, can you give an example of the rest of your pipeline so that we can better explain where the geoNear command may fit into it?

Comment: (c) then you could do something along the lines of `db.places.aggregate([{$geoNear: {near: [40.724, -73.997], distanceField: "dist.calculated", maxDistance: 10, query: { type: "pizza" }}}, {$group: {_id: 1, minPrice: { $min: "$price"}}}])` to spit out the _id and price of pizza at the cheapest pizza place.

Comment: * Sorry, the _id in the result will be 1, and the minPrice accurate.

Comment: The problem is that you can not predict the filter that will be used, the user will choose. The application is written in Java, from this link:

I am using the following schema:
http://picpaste.com/filter-Sp50Bxm1.png

An example of the code:
http://pastebin.com/BhKgPpuv

It is very important that the output iterator is this, I can not predict the JSON, depends on user input. May have 20 text fields, number etc..

I already have all pipelines ready to filter by date, sort text, regex etc., Lacking only GPS = /

TKS

Comment: Right, so in your case, you would pass the filters previously passed to `$match` into the `query` field. I.E. `db.places.aggregate([{$geoNear: {near: [40.724, -73.997], distanceField: "dist.calculated", maxDistance: 10, query: { MATCH OPTIONS HERE }}}, OTHER AGG OPTIONS HERE])` Does that make sense?

Comment: Alright, thank you Amalia. I understood your affirmation and got to use in first pipeline the operation geolocation and my solution worked. Thanks a lot with your patience with me. This real solution is yours. Very very thank you :D