# mongodb, finding and sorting by geoNear and date in MongoTemplate in spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

How to find the nearest and the newest objects to a point in mongodb using spring boot MongoTemplate. I tried many ways but it always sorts by date or nearest location only not both.

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777130/mongodb-sorting-by-geonear-and-date) issue but I couldn't understand the solution number 1 and the second one didn't work with me.

I would appreciat any help!

Comment: The first solution just sorts by date in code after the results were fetched for each iteration.

Comment: What didn't work in the second one?  That's the way to go.   Give us some sample docs (actually 3 or 4) with the geo distance and dates set up in a way such that a sort by distance and date as you understand it yields the order you seek.